# How to remove data from DataFrame permanently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After reading CSV data file with:

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print df.shape
```

I get DataFrame 99 rows (indexes) long:

```
(99, 2)
```

To cleanup DataFrame I go ahead and apply dropna() method which reduces it to 33 rows:

```
df = df.dropna()
print df.shape
```

which prints:

```
(33, 2)
```

Now when I iterate the columns it prints out all 99 rows like they weren't dropped:

```
for index, value in df['column1'].iteritems():
    print index
```

which gives me this:

```
0
1
2
.
.
.
97
98
99
```

It appears the `dropna()` simply made the data "hidden". That hidden data returns back when I iterate DataFrame. How to assure the dropped data is removed from DataFrame instead just getting hidden?

Comment: it's preserved the index row labels, if you want to reset the index then call `reset_index`, you will find that your index is missing some row values after `dropna`

Comment: You rock! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Please post it as an answer so we could score it.

Comment: @EdChum Yes, please do. Otherwise schmucks like me will go and post in your place and deny you of due credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're being confused by the fact that the row labels have been preserved so the last row label is still `99`.

Example:

```
In [2]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,np.NaN, np.NaN, 4]})
df

Out[2]:
    a
0   0
1   1
2 NaN
3 NaN
4   4
```

After calling `dropna` the index row labels are preserved:

```
In [3]:
df = df.dropna()
df

Out[3]:
   a
0  0
1  1
4  4
```

If you want to reset so that they are contiguous then call [`reset_index(drop=True)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to assign a new index:

```
In [4]:
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df

Out[4]:
   a
0  0
1  1
2  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just adjust parameters for example:

```
Df =  df.dropna(inplace=True)
```